# Infura API for mobile(ionic) app

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, dapps

I have one little question. Suppose I have private key of user in ionic app. Is this enough to make transactions using infura API and web3?

Comment: Yes that is the only thing needed.

Comment: do you mean the API key to the development kit of Ionic or the private key of an Ethereum account?

Comment: Ethereum account private key

Answer (score 1):

Yes!
And the only challenge is how are you going to save that private key in the mobile app. A high level of security is required in order for the users to trust your app.
In addition you should provide a way to restore private keys created in the app, either bu providing a 12-word seed like metamask and other crypto wallet managers.

Comment: Can you please share with a coding example?